# Modify Local Shared Object with javascript or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3, flash, cookies

In my previous question I tried to figure out how to identify a computer as accurate as possible. I think the best solution is the usage of *Local Shared Objects* a.k.a *flash cookies*. I would like to create a flash object, and two *JavaScript* or *PHP* functions to communicate with it. I did a research in the mayor search engines, but I did not found any solution to do that. I only want to store one variable in the object. I have no experience in ActionScripting...

Is there any way to create a local shared object and manipulate it with PHP or JS?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?, if you want to store data on clients computer why don't you use php cookies.

Comment: @user1910290 I would like to prevent users to increase some counters on my site, with cheating with cookies.

Comment: you can't do this reliably. if someone wants to, they can bypass ANY restrictions you put in quite easily. even just manually opening/closing "porn mode" browser windows repeatedly.